# fancybox vertical responsiveness

Tags: jquery, css, fancybox, fancybox-2

I've tried to get to the bottom of this a few times but with little luck.. 
I already know about issue with isotope on same page as fancybox- i dont believe that is causing my issue. Basically- my fancybox fills in whitespace on the left/right of frame instead of being responsive to fill the space.

go to http://defyordie.com/testbed/ and click on one of the work thumbs. Royal slider inside fancybox.
Fancybox will not adapt vertically until the window is huge on a 30 inch monitor

http://defyordie.com/testbed/images/stacksample.jpg

Comment: have you tried `fitToView: false`? ... and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: added that.. now the fancybox is HUGE and goes way off screen :P
and apologies if i didnt ask the question correctly.

Comment: you may need to ask a `maxWidth` option so it will always fit horizontally but still off screen vertically if the content is longer

Comment: if i have fittoview false and maxwidth set to say 1600 then it just loads at maxwidth automatically and loses responsiveness for smaller screens. I'd post the particular code here but it's too long

Comment: right, `maxWidth` should be combined with `fitToView: true`

Comment: firstly, i very much appreciate your help. Its been difficult getting solid input on my issue. Secondly, setting my maxwidth and fittoview leaves me where i was before- fancybox is responsive horizontally but not vertically. I can make my window huge and it just opens as one long row. Could it be an issue with the royalslider inside my fancybox? I've used fancybox before and not had this issue.. royalslider is the only variable

Comment: ack i just figured it out! It WAS an issue with royalslider. No wonder it was driving me crazy. I had autoScaleSlider: true, but what i needed was the missing autoScaleSliderHeight/Width settings. Adding values to those made the royalslider push the fancybox responsively. Very happy :) Thanks again for your time and help!